# How to render a specific view according a flow param in grails flow?

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

I need to change the gsp to render dynamically according certain params. the thing is: in the render action I get
`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.metaclass.PropertyExpression@680dc2a` instead of the params I passed.

```
 promoFlow = {
   start {
    action {
     flow.inputPage = "landing1/input/${params.land}" 
     flow.pinPage = "landing1/pin/${params.land}"
     flow.finishPage = "landing1/finish/${params.land}"
        ...
         success()
        ... 
 }on('success'){
    ...
     }.to 'preview'
  }
   preview {
  render(view: flow.inputPage ) 
      on('next') {...}.to 'pin'
  }
```

Comment: have you tried a `"landing1/input/${params.land.value}"`

Answer (score 0):

Paul if you are using Grails2 why not add a parameter to the action method instead of accessing the params directly, eg:

```
def myAction(String land) {
   ...
   flow.inputPage = "landing1/input/${land}" 
   ...
}
```